# What is the source of the cert and pem files used with simplesamlphp

Tags: simplesamlphp

I have simplesamlphp working with a production site. There are three forms of credential used: a cert file and pem file in the same folder, and a string from a pem file provided by the government active directory folks, which is inserted in the the meta file saml20-idp-remote.php. In getting SAML working with this site when assigned the task, all 3 files were already present.

Now I am needing to get SAML working with the staging environment, as well. I received the file that's content gets inserted in the meta file. What I cannot figure out is what the source of the other two files would be, and whether they would be unique for this environment or the same as the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

These are the SAML signing or encryption certificates for your installation and you can generate them yourself. They are unique per environment. See the manual for how to do this: https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp#section_1_1